# Similar Book Recommendations

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

Chodesh Tov,

I just finished reading As A Driven Leaf by Milton Steinberg and I truly enjoyed it. I feel the book spoke to me and the questions I am struggling with religiously. I was wondering if you guys could recommend me a similar book that influenced or was impactful in your religious/spiritual journey?

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.jewishbookcouncil.org/book/the-orchard

Comment: https://mobile.twitter.com/AriKahn1/status/1268827506959941632

Comment: It would be much easier to answer the question if you say more about the book you read and/or the themes you are trying to explore

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider [Rabbi Lawrence Kelemen](https://www.lawrencekelemen.com/pages/about-us)'s two books:

[Permission to Believe](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Permission-Believe-Rational-Approaches-Existence/dp/0944070558/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=permission%20to%20believe&qid=1592824470&s=books&sr=1-1)

**Review on Amazon:**
The most perplexing question of all times: does G-d really exist?
And is it really irrational to believe so?
World renowned lecturer and educator Rabbi Lawrence Kelemen, Harvard graduate, examines the case for G-d in this intellectually groundbreaking book. A well-researched and footnoted work, this is an essential read for any individual with intellectual curiosity and spiritual thirst, and anyone who is involved in Jewish outreach.

[Permission to Receive](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Permission-Receive-Rational-Approaches-Torahs/dp/1568710992/ref=rtpb_2/258-2423534-7805438?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=1568710992&pd_rd_r=b4f3eca0-7950-4c08-a926-31d9fe56b7d5&pd_rd_w=H1ytv&pd_rd_wg=mI59w&pf_rd_p=5bc68382-a034-465d-b5d1-a304bfdf2f38&pf_rd_r=EQDC3WZ6YGM21XSZPYPK&psc=1&refRID=EQDC3WZ6YGM21XSZPYPK)

**Review on Amazon:**
Is the Torah really Divine?
In this sequel to the groundbreaking work Permission to Believe, world renowned lecturer and educator Rabbi Lawrence Keleman, Harvard graduate, presents four rational reasons to support the Divine origin of the Torah. Those who passionately value both intellectual integrity and their spiritual inheritance and those separated from their Jewish heritage only by healthy skepticism, will find in this book Permission to Receive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the book you read, so I don't know if it's similar. But I highly recommend "[Lieutenant Birnbaum][1]."

It's the autobiography of Meyer Birnbaum z"l. He was drafted and served during WWII, liberating the camps and helping the prisoners afterwards. (He was the translator for General Eisenhower in the camps, among other rare opportunities that he had.)

He has tremendous stories there, first his first hand account (including lots of pre-war and post-war as well) and he discusses a lot of the lessons he learned throughout his amazingly productive life.

He deals with major issues like:

-dealing with antisemitism

-the role of a religious Jew in the world

-understanding how G-d interacts with us, and accepting what can't be understood

and much more.

I received this book as a little kid when it first came out, and it made a tremendous impact on me.
Later when I came to Israel to study I had the good fortune to meet him in person and connect with him a little bit. He lived the lessons that he had learned throughout his long, productive life.
[1]: https://www.artscroll.com/Products/LTBH.html